# Calling future in recover partial method

Tags: scala, future

I have partial method `defaultRecover` helping to recover from exception:

```
  def getName(length: Int): Future[String] = {
    if (length > 0)
      Future.successful("john")
    else
      Future.failed(new RuntimeException("failed"))
  }

  def defaultRecover: PartialFunction[Throwable, String] = {
    case _ => "jane"
  }

  // easy and working
  val res = getName(0) recover {
    defaultRecover
  }
```

Now the problem. I defined second recovery method `emergencyRecover` and I want to choose which recovery method will be used based on result of another call - `isEmergency()`.

```
  def emergencyRecover: PartialFunction[Throwable, String] = {
    case _ => "arnold"
  }

  // simplified - this actually calls REST API
  def isEmergency(): Future[Boolean] = {
    Future.successful(true)
  }

  // type mismatch
  // required: PartialFunction[Throwable,String]
  // found   : Future[PartialFunction[Throwable,String]]
  val res = getName(0) recover {
    isEmergency() map {
      case false => defaultRecover
      case true => emergencyRecover
    }
  }
```

But I am getting type mismatch. How can I achieve this kind of error handling? Do I need to use another approach than recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I always say, the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html) is your friend. You can use `recoverWith`.
Also, remember it receives a partial function, so you have to do something like:

```
val res = getName(0) recoverWith {
  case e => isEmergency() map {
    case false => defaultRecover(e)
    case true  => emergencyRecover(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use recoverWith instead:

```
  val res2 = getName(0) recoverWith {
    case _ =>  isEmergency().map {
      case false => "jane"
      case true => "arnold"
    }
  }
```